# Issue with Email Logo aligned right in Lightning

Tags: email, lightning, email-template

I have a custom HTML email template, which includes an Image as a header. The image is nested in a table as follows:

```
<table style= "width: 100%; background-color: #09C" cellpadding= '0' cellspacing= '0'>
<tr>
<td>
<img alt="Skycure Support Logo" src="https://XXXXXX.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=XXXXXXX&oid=XXXXXXX"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I send out email with this template, the logo appears properly aligned left as it should, and also appears so when selecting 'view email' and viewing the Email object: 
[image]

For some reason, when viewing the Email in the Lightning Case Feed, the logo is aligned right:
[image]

Did anyone experience that issue? Any leads on how to resolve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding 'text-align' attribute to the 'td' element:

```
<td style="text-align:left">
```